# How do I get readNetFromTensorflow to read my model?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and OpenCV. I want to train a model, then use the trained model to look over an image and see if there is a match. When I pass my frozen model in to cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow I get the following error:

> C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_graph_simplifier.cpp:860: error: (-215:Assertion failed) nodesMapIt != nodesMap.end() in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190122::sortByExecutionOrder'

At first I thought that my frozen model was to blame, so I downloaded a new one from the model zoo located here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

I have also tried adding in my pbtxt file as well, and this does produce a different error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:616: error: (-215:Assertion failed) const_layers.insert(std::make_pair(name, li)).second in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190122::`anonymous-namespace'::addConstNodes'

Here is what little code I have so far:

```py
import numpy as np

import argparse

import cv2

import tensorflow as tf

tfNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("myPath\\model.pb","myPath\\model.pbtxt")
```